# How to fix the POST "ValidationError" if the validation is supposed to be ok?

Tags: node.js, validation, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am making a delivery app. 
When I try to POST an order request in Postman with all the required data, I get the following error for every object:

```
"message": "order validation failed: recipient.recLocation.recPhone: Path `recipient.recLocation.recPhone` is required., recipient.recLocation.recZipcode: Path `recipient.recLocation.recZipcode` is required., recipient.recLocation.recStreetnumber: Path `recipient.recLocation.recStreetnumber` is required., recipient.recLocation.recStreet: Path `recipient.recLocation.recStreet` is required., recipient.recLocation.recCity: Path `recipient.recLocation.recCity` is required., recipient.recName: Path `recipient.recName` is required.",
```

So basically, none of my requests pass. I looked around and according to what I've found on previous answers here and on Google, both my mongoose model and my route file seem to be perfectly fine.
Here is the snippet from the model for the "recipient":

```js
recipient: {
    //rec in front of field names stands for "recipient" - done so that the data of recipient doesn't get confused for the data of the sender
    recName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    recLocation: {
      recCity: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 32
      },
      recStreet: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 32
      },
      recStreetnumber: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 16
      },
      recZipcode: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 16
      },
      recPhone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        max: 32
      }
    }
  }
```

And here is the snippet from the routing file:

```js
    const orderFields = {};
    orderFields.user = req.user.id;
    if (req.body.description) orderFields.description = req.body.description;
    if (req.body.status) orderFields.status = req.body.status;
    //recipient
    orderFields.recipient = {};
    if (req.body.recName) orderFields.recipient.recName = req.body.recName;
    if (req.body.recCity) orderFields.recipient.recCity = req.body.recCity;
    if (req.body.recStreet)
      orderFields.recipient.recStreet = req.body.recStreet;
    if (req.body.recStreetnumber)
      orderFields.recipient.recStreetnumber = req.body.recStreetnumber;
    if (req.body.recZipcode)
      orderFields.recipient.recZipcode = req.body.recZipcode;
    if (req.body.recPhone) orderFields.recipient.recPhone = req.body.recPhone;
```

I am guessing my way of setting the path is wrong, but I did it according to what I've found by Googling and exploring other questions around here.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

[This is what I'm trying to pass in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr5wi.png)

Also, when I change the above snippet from the routing file to:

```js
    orderFields.recipient = {};
    if (req.body.recName) orderFields.recipient.recName = req.body.recName;
    if (req.body.recCity)
      orderFields.recipient.recLocation.recCity = req.body.recCity;
    if (req.body.recStreet)
      orderFields.recipient.recLocation.recStreet = req.body.recStreet;
    if (req.body.recStreetnumber)
      orderFields.recipient.recLocation.recStreetnumber =
        req.body.recStreetnumber;
    if (req.body.recZipcode)
      orderFields.recipient.recLocation.recZipcode = req.body.recZipcode;
    if (req.body.recPhone)
      orderFields.recipient.recLocation.recPhone = req.body.recPhone;
```

I get a different error:
[2nd Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xU7Uq.png)

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with your POST request. Can you please edit your question and add what exactly are you sending?

Comment: @MrMister I added what I'm sending

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you should pass a request with a hierarchical body instead of flatting out the fields. The `recipient` model describes a `recLocation` that has 5 required fields, and you are indeed supplying them – but in the wrong place.

Try to post a JSON request that depicts the location likewise:

```
recLocation: {
   reqCity: "..."
   reqStreet: "..."
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Removed the recipient in the model, left only recLocation and it works. Here is the screenshot of the successful JSON request: https://prnt.sc/n445e1

Answer (score -1):

There are well-documented packages available, Express validator is very easy to implement. You don't need to create large if condition inside function. 
Please follow  [this](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) link.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, my validation isn't the problem. The validation is working, which is why I have this error. The request does not pass the data, so I'm almost 100% sure my error lies within the snippet from the routing file I provided. I just can't see what's wrong in it.